# Cannot run Docker Windows container with GPU and CUDA

Tags: windows, docker, opencv, gpu, darknet

I have object detection app that uses machine learning approach and it is GPU-based with CUDA.
I have .dll files that are necessary to run app. Everything works well on my laptop.

But I need to dockerize the solution. Because of dll files, I have to use windows container. The problem is with GPU and CUDA which is necessary for dlls. I am not able to create docker image in windows that use GPU and CUDA. It seems that it is not problem for Linux. But it is possible for windows?

Here is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-windowsservercore

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY opencv_core420.dll .
COPY opencv_highgui420.dll .
COPY opencv_imgcodecs420.dll .
COPY opencv_imgproc420.dll .
COPY opencv_videoio420.dll .
COPY pthreadGC2.dll .
COPY pthreadVC2.dll .
COPY darknet.dll .

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: opencv v4.2.0 is out of date. no issues are accepted on outdated versions.

Comment: Does your docker container have gpu hardware access at all? Afair Nvidia has its own special docker version with gpu access?

Comment: the cuda regulars keep removing the cuda tag from these questions.